# An exception occurred processing JSP page /index.jsp at line 39

Tags: jsp, web

I really don't know what is wrong with my code .Help~

HTTP Status 500 - An exception occurred processing JSP page /index.jsp at line 39
type Exception report

message An exception occurred processing JSP page /index.jsp at line 39

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /index.jsp at line 39

```
36:         <c:forEach items="${list }" var="movie">
37:             <tr data-genuitec="wc1-0-18">
38:     
39:                 <td data-genuitec="wc1-0-19">${movie.moviename }</td>       
40:                 <td data-genuitec="wc1-0-20">${movie.time }</td>
41:                 <td data-genuitec="wc1-0-21">${movie.endtime }</td>
42:                 <td data-genuitec="wc1-0-22">${movie.price }</td>
```

Comment: Provide your exception. It is not clear what you want.

Comment: I added it,but I don't know if it will be helpful

Comment: What is the WHOLE exception?